# Using pgfplot externalize with .eps output in letter 10cm*10cm

Tags: pgfplots

Using `pgfplots`, externalize an `.avi` file and 
using `DVI>ps`, externalize an `.eps` file on A4 but I want a figure with width and height of 10cm in letter (10cm x 10cm). How can I make it?

(If you know how to make a figure that be equal the page size.)

this is my code.
‎

```
\documentclass{report}‎
‎\usepackage{pgfplots}‎
‎\usepgfplotslibrary{external}‎
‎\tikzexternalize{question}‎
‎\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{15 cm}‎ 
‎\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{15 cm}‎ 
‎\newpage‎
‎\thispagestyle{empty}‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,height=10cm}‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}‎
 ‎\begin{axis}[‎
   ‎xlabel={$x$}‎,
   ‎ylabel={\textbf{ $f(x)$‎ }}
   ]
   ‎\addplot {x^2};‎
   ‎\addplot {x^3};‎
 ‎\end{axis}‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
‎\end{document}
```

Comment: do you want to convert an `.avi` file to `.eps`?

Comment: Will `\centering{\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{your tikz file}}` be useful? You have to include `graphicx` package for this.

Comment: @HarishKumar Could you post this as an answer (with a little explanation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize an image or picture to desired dimensions, you can either use `\resizebox` from `graphicx` package or `adjustbox` from `adjustbox` package.

The syntax for `resizebox` is

```
\resizebox{width}{height}{your tikz file}
```

If you want to keep the aspect ration the height can be replaced by `!`.

The full code will be

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
...
...
\begingroup
\centering
{\resizebox{10cm}{10cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}‎
 ‎\begin{axis}[‎
   ‎xlabel={$x$}‎,
   ‎ylabel={\textbf{ $f(x)$‎ }}
   ]
   ‎\addplot {x^2};‎
   ‎\addplot {x^3};‎
 ‎\end{axis}‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎‎}}
\endgroup
```

But giving both width and height as 10cm may not keep the aspect ratio intact. Hence putting `\resizebox{10cm}{!}{...` will adjust the height so as to keep the aspect ratio.

The adjustbox may be used as

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
...
...
...

\begin{adjustbox}{width=10cm,height=10cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ..
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
```